# Speeding up this procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My table has over 100K records and proper indexes are already there. This is my stored procedure which takes almost 1.2 seconds and is unacceptable at the moment:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextAndPreviousInsturmentID]
(
    @AccountID      int,
    @JurisdictionID int,
    @InstrumentID   varchar(14),
    @PreviousInstrumentID   varchar(14) OUT,
    @NextInstrumentID   varchar(14) OUT,
    @PreviousDocumentID int OUT,
    @NextDocumentID int OUT,
    @ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID  bit OUT,
    @ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID  bit OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @RowNum int = 0
    Declare @PreviousCreatedByAccountID         int = 0
    Declare @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID    int = 0
    Declare @NextCreatedByAccountID             int = 0
    Declare @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID        int = 0

    Select @RowNum = RowNum
    From
    (
        Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by RecordingDateTime) as RowNum, InstrumentID
                From Documents Where RecordingDateTime IS NOT NULL
    ) v where v.InstrumentID = @InstrumentID


    ;With normal As
    (   
        Select  ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by RecordingDateTime) as RowNum, 
                DocumentID, 
                CreatedByAccountID, 
                JurisdictionID,
                InstrumentID            
            From Documents  Where RecordingDateTime IS NOT NULL
    )
    SELECT
        @PreviousInstrumentID            = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN InstrumentID       END),
        @PreviousDocumentID              = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN DocumentID         END),
        @PreviousCreatedByAccountID      = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN CreatedByAccountID END),
        @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN JurisdictionID     END),
        @NextInstrumentID                = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN InstrumentID       END),
        @NextDocumentID                  = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN DocumentID         END),
        @NextCreatedByAccountID          = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN CreatedByAccountID END),
        @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID     = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN JurisdictionID     END)
    FROM normal
    WHERE RowNum IN (@RowNum - 1, @RowNum + 1)


    if @JurisdictionID > 0 
    Begin
        If @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID = @JurisdictionID
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID = 0
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID = 1
        End

        If @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID = @JurisdictionID
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID = 0
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID = 1
        End

    End
    Else If @AccountID > 0
    Begin

        If @NextCreatedByAccountID = @AccountID
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID = 0
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID = 1
        End

        If @PreviousCreatedByAccountID = @AccountID
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID = 0
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Set @ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID = 1
        End

    End
    Else
    Begin
        Set @ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID = 1
        Set @ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID = 1
    End

    Set @PreviousInstrumentID = IsNull(@PreviousInstrumentID,'')
    Set @NextInstrumentID = IsNull(@NextInstrumentID,'')
    Set @PreviousDocumentID = IsNull(@PreviousDocumentID,0)
    Set @NextDocumentID = IsNull(@NextDocumentID,0)
    Set @ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID = ISNULL(@ShowPublicPageForPreviousInstrumentID,0)
    Set @ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID = IsNull(@ShowPublicPageForNextInstrumentID,0)
END
```

This is my table definition along with indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [DocumentID] [int] IDENTITY(1000001,1) NOT NULL,
    [IGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ITypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [JudgementTypeID] [smallint] NULL,
    [JurisdictionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Remarks] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedByAccountID] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID] [int] NULL,
    [InternalNotes] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ParentDocumentID] [int] NULL,
    [DocumentStatusID] [tinyint] NULL,
    [FilingNumber] [int] NULL,
    [EfileDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EfiledByUserID] [int] NULL,
    [ACEfileCreditCardID] [int] NULL,
    [ACEfileBankAccountID] [int] NULL,
    [StampData] [varchar](1024) NULL,
    [InstrumentID] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [ApprovedBy] [int] NULL,
    [RecordingDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Receipt] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [ReceiptNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsReEfiled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OldInstrumentID] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [IsChanged] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsUpdatedAfterChanged] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_Documents] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ACEfileBankAccountID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ACEfileBankAccountID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [ACEfileBankAccountID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ApprovedBy],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ACEfileCreditCardID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ACEfileCreditCardID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [ACEfileCreditCardID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ApprovedBy]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ApprovedBy] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [ApprovedBy] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_CreatedByAccountID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CreatedByAccountID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [CreatedByAccountID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [InstrumentID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_CreatedByJurisdictionID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CreatedByJurisdictionID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [CreatedByAccountID],
    [InstrumentID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_DocumentDate]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DocumentDate] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [DocumentDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_DocumentStatusID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DocumentStatusID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [DocumentStatusID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [DocumentID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_EfileDate]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EfileDate] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [EfileDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [UserID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IGroupID],
    [InstrumentID],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [StampData],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_EfiledByUserID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EfiledByUserID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [EfiledByUserID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ITypeID],
    [IGroupID],
    [InstrumentID],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_FilingNumber]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FilingNumber] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [FilingNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_IDate]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IDate] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [IDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [EfileDate],
    [UserID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IGroupID],
    [InstrumentID],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [StampData],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_IGroupID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IGroupID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [IGroupID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [UserID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [Remarks],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ImportedFromInstrumentID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ImportedFromInstrumentID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_InstrumentID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_InstrumentID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [InstrumentID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [OldInstrumentID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ITypeID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ITypeID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [ITypeID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [IGroupID],
    [UserID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [Remarks],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_JurisdictionID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_JurisdictionID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [JurisdictionID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_LastStatusChangedDateTime]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LastStatusChangedDateTime] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IGroupID],
    [InstrumentID],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [StampData],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_OldInstrumentID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_OldInstrumentID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [OldInstrumentID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [InstrumentID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [StampData],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_ParentDocumentID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ParentDocumentID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [ParentDocumentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_RecordingDateTime]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RecordingDateTime] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [RecordingDateTime] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ApprovedBy],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IGroupID],
    [InstrumentID],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentDate],
    [Remarks],
    [UserID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [StampData],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_UserID]    Script Date: 3/13/2013 5:17:53 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserID] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    [UserID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [DocumentDate],
    [ACEfileCreditCardID],
    [ACEfileBankAccountID],
    [ApprovedBy],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [DocumentStatusID],
    [DocumentID],
    [IGroupID],
    [ITypeID],
    [IDate],
    [JudgementTypeID],
    [Remarks],
    [CreatedByAccountID],
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    [InternalNotes],
    [ParentDocumentID],
    [FilingNumber],
    [EfileDate],
    [EfiledByUserID],
    [StampData],
    [InstrumentID],
    [RecordingDateTime],
    [Receipt],
    [ReceiptNo],
    [IsReEfiled],
    [OldInstrumentID],
    [LastStatusChangedDateTime],
    [ImportedFromInstrumentID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Is there any way I can speed up this query? Basically I am trying to fetch next and previous. So if I pass in some instrument ID, I try to find its previous and next record.

This is my Lag / Lead query (new function - slow performance :()

```
;With normal As
    (   
        Select  Top 100 Percent
                InstrumentID, 
                Lead(d.InstrumentID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LeadInstrumentID, 
                Lag(d.InstrumentID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LagInstrumentID,
                DocumentID,
                Lead(d.DocumentID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LeadDocumentID, 
                Lag(d.DocumentID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LagDocumentID, 
                CreatedByAccountID,
                Lead(d.CreatedByAccountID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LeadCreatedByAccountID, 
                Lag(d.CreatedByAccountID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LagCreatedByAccountID, 
                JurisdictionID,
                Lead(d.JurisdictionID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LeadJurisdictionID, 
                Lag(d.JurisdictionID) Over (Order By RecordingDateTime) as LagJurisdictionID


        From Documents d Where RecordingDateTime IS NOT NULL
            Order by RecordingDateTime
    )
    SELECT
        @PreviousInstrumentID            = LagInstrumentID,
        @PreviousDocumentID              = LagDocumentID,
        @PreviousCreatedByAccountID      = LagCreatedByAccountID,
        @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID = LagJurisdictionID,
        @NextInstrumentID                = LeadInstrumentID,
        @NextDocumentID                  = LeadDocumentID,
        @NextCreatedByAccountID          = LeadCreatedByAccountID,
        @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID     = LeadJurisdictionID
    FROM normal n
        Where n.InstrumentID = @InstrumentID
```

Now I already have a index on InstrumentID and yet this query is worse than my previous one taking 2 seconds in SSMS.

This is what I end up having - 3 separate queries:

```
Declare @RecordingDateTime  datetime

    Select @RecordingDateTime = RecordingDateTime
        From Documents d Where d.InstrumentID = @InstrumentID

    Select  Top 1   @PreviousInstrumentID          =  InstrumentID ,
                    @PreviousDocumentID            = DocumentID  ,
                    @PreviousCreatedByAccountID    =  CreatedByAccountID,
                    @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID = JurisdictionID 
        From Documents d 
            Where d.RecordingDateTime < @RecordingDateTime
                Order By d.RecordingDateTime Desc

    Select  Top 1   @NextInstrumentID          =  InstrumentID ,
                    @NextDocumentID            = DocumentID  ,
                    @NextCreatedByAccountID    =  CreatedByAccountID,
                    @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID = JurisdictionID 
        From Documents d 
            Where d.RecordingDateTime > @RecordingDateTime
                Order By d.RecordingDateTime
```

The duration for this query is just `25` as noted in SQL profiler

Comment: I wonder if this could be better optimized by avoiding processing a single record and looking for its predecessor and successor.  Instead, process the whole dataset in ordered sequence.  For that, I would need to see what is calling the stored procedure.

Comment: Probably. Using `LAG` and `LEAD`. You need to explain what it is supposed to do though. Unless InstrumentId is unique it is undeterminsitic at the moment what is the result of `Select @RowNum = RowNum` and unless `RecordingDateTime` is also unique the row numbering bit is undeterministic.

Comment: @MartinSmith: InstrumentId is always unique.

Comment: Also can you supply the complete table definition including indexes?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I've posted the table definition along with indexes. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Aargh I'm somewhere without 2012 access but I would evaluate both the plans when using `LAG`/`LEAD` and three separate queries as suggested by @wallyk. [Example code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1c31/6)

Comment: @Martin: I tried Lag Lead and it was worse. I'd suggest never to use this function. This is awfully slow took about 2 seconds even in SSMS even though I have index. I'll try your concept of three separate queries.

Comment: @Martin: I ended up having your concept of having 3 queries and I get results in 25 milliseconds as noted in profiler :). Lesson learnt - never try to be fancy using new functions when it can be done more beautifully using simpler ones.

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with ROW_NUMBER() and its like whenever I get near the 100K row mark or more (definitely with the 1M mark or more).